# How to decode "rctg a fvfvyv mugmgkh"?

Tags: cipher

Here's a puzzle that I created. Hope you enjoy!

What does this message say?:

```
rctg a fvfvyv mugmgkh
```

Here are some hints:

> Uses two ciphers.

Hint 2:

> r13

Hint 3:

> Use an anagram of the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution?

> Based on the hints, I first applied a ROT13 to turn "rctg a fvfvyv mugmgkh" into "epgt n sisili zhtztxu."
>
> Then I tried to decode it as a rail fence cipher, but I wasn't able to get a meaningful phrase from the results.
>
> I tried just looking for anagrams of the given letters and found "THIS IS PUZZLING TEXT" which seems like a plausible solution.

Comment: @ShivSitaram I used a rail fence cipher encoding/decoding tool with 7 rails, and there was no way to get this phrase out. Are you sure you encrypted it correctly? Here's the tool I used: https://www.boxentriq.com/code-breaking/rail-fence-cipher

Comment: @ShivSitaram This is what I get when I try to encode your message with 7 rails: https://i.imgur.com/XmulIec.png. What are you doing differently?

Comment: also https://www.dcode.fr/rail-fence-cipher does not find correct result, there is some mistake or  slightly different subvariant, if you start from the right side it seems to collect every 4th lcharacter.

Comment: Oh, I realized my mistake. There seems to have been a problem with the encoding that I did. Thanks for solving it! I fixed the OP for future solvers...

Answer (score 0):

Is it perhaps

> dCode Cassette

My method

> I brute forced the code through rot13 first, looked at the hints, rot13’d it and then K7’d it. Couldn’t find any ciphers/codes named 7r except this Babylon 5 thing that I have no knowledge about.

I used all the hints.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is incorrect. Could you explain your steps and interpretation of the hints? Thanks!

Comment: Bother, I thought it was right. It seemed correct.Rot13 (V oehgr sbeprq gur pbqr guebhtu ebg13 svefg, ybbxrq ng gur uvagf, ebg13’q vg naq gura X7’q vg. Pbhyqa’g svaq nal pvcuref/pbqrf anzrq 7e rkprcg guvf Onolyba 5 guvat gung V unir ab xabjyrqtr nobhg. Vf gur Onolyba 5 guvat vzcbegnag?)